# Getting this error - CS0649 Field 'MainActivity.button1' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Tags: c#

This is my code, I'm completely new to C# but got challenged to make a button that changes TextView to say goodbye when clicked.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using System;
using Java.Interop;
using Xamarin.Android.Net;

namespace FHoek
{
    [Activity(Label = "FHoek", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private Button button1 ;
        private TextView textView1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
        public void ButtonPushed() {
            button1.Click += Button1_Click;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textView1.Text = ("Goodbye");
        }
    }


}
```

And the xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="hello"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <Button
        android:text="End"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="ButtonPushed"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure  what the problem is here. I'm getting this error for both button1 and textView1.

Comment: I see two issues 1)  You need to call the button constructor : button1 = new Button() 2) You need to register the button.  I don't see how you are getting to the code : button1.Click += Button1_Click;  You need to do this before the button is pushed otherwise the push will not work.

Comment: When I call the constructor and add that code I get an error that say Button does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. This "button1.Click += Button1_Click;" I added because it was one of the quick fix options and I'm just trying to figure it out.

Comment: Do not know what type button you are using.  Right click Button and select go to definition.

Comment: Should be : button1 = new Button(this); and  textView1 = new TextView(this);

Comment: I managed to figure it out, thanks for the help.